# Inserting Data in a String into a DataTable

Tags: c#, xml, datatable

I have this DataTable:

```
DataTable callsDT = new DataTable();
callsDT.Columns.Add("id", typeof(Int32));
callsDT.Columns.Add("origination", typeof(String));
callsDT.Columns.Add("start_time", typeof(DateTime));
callsDT.Columns.Add("from", typeof(String));
callsDT.Columns.Add("from_name", typeof(String));
callsDT.Columns.Add("from_number", typeof(Int32));
```

I have a list of strings taken from an XML file that look like this:

```
  <call id="55555" origination="incoming" start_time="2001-01-01 00:00:00" from_name="John Doe" from_number="5555555555 </call>
```

I need to iterate through each string and assign each data point to a variable but am struggling to come up with an elegant way of doing that.

Comment: Look at ReadXml method of dataset

Comment: It's somewhat unclear from your example whether that XML element constitutes only one string (i.e. each such string corresponds to one data table row), or if the various attribute values are the strings making up the list of strings that you mention (i.e. there will only be one data table row). (Btw. you're missing a double quote at the end of `from_number`.)

Answer (score 0):

Much easier to use ReadXML and WriteXML methods like code below.  You need to put DataTable into a DataSet to be able to use this method.  You are missing one column in your input string (from name) and you last int32 needs to be a long.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Data;


namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        const string FILENAME1 = @"C:\temp\test.xml";

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            DataTable callsDT = new DataTable();
            ds.Tables.Add(callsDT);
            callsDT.Columns.Add("id", typeof(Int32));
            callsDT.Columns.Add("origination", typeof(String));
            callsDT.Columns.Add("start_time", typeof(DateTime));
            callsDT.Columns.Add("from", typeof(String));
            callsDT.Columns.Add("from_name", typeof(String));
            callsDT.Columns.Add("from_number", typeof(long));

            List<List<object>> input = new List<List<object>>(){
               new List<object>() {55555, "incoming", DateTime.Parse("2001-01-01 00:00:00"), "John",  "Doe", 5555555555},
               new List<object>() {55556, "incoming", DateTime.Parse("2001-01-02 00:00:00"), "Mary",  "Smith", 5555555556},
               new List<object>() {55557, "incoming", DateTime.Parse("2001-01-03 00:00:00"), "Rob",  "Robon", 55555555557},
               new List<object>() {55558, "incoming", DateTime.Parse("2001-01-04 00:00:00"), "Sally",  "Rode", 5555555558}
            };

            foreach(List<object> newRow in input)
            {
                callsDT.Rows.Add(newRow.ToArray());
            }

            ds.WriteXml(FILENAME1, XmlWriteMode.WriteSchema);

            ds = null;
            ds = new DataSet();
            ds.ReadXml(FILENAME1, XmlReadMode.ReadSchema);


        }
    }
}
​
```

Comment: Of course, this only works if the XML can be represented as a set of DataTables. Sometimes, it cannot.

Comment: John : It always can be made to be a set of tables, sometimes these tables are useless due to the organization.  Once the level of tags in a XML file get to be 5 the XML tables get to be too fragmented to be practical.

Comment: It cannot always be made to be a set of tables. I had a case once where ReadXml tried to create a grandchild table which would have been a child of two different parent tables. That's not permitted.

Comment: But it ran and didn't give an exception.

Comment: I mean that _this particular_ XML may fit into table, but not every possible XML document can fit into tables.

Comment: Never seen an XML that wouldn't go into a dataset.  Some weren't very useful.